# VIM does not detect syntax of .ssh/config

Tags: ssh, vim, syntax-highlighting

```
vi ~/.ssh/config
  :set syn?
  >syntax=conf
```

When I do:

```
set syn=sshconfig
```

Then the syntax highlighting is as it should be.

Why isn't the filetype automatically identified? And how can it be set automatically?

Comment: It works correctly for me. What version of Vim do you have? (:version within Vim, or vim --version on the command line)

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3

Comment: What does ":verbose set filetype?" (include the question mark as part of the command) show when you have opened .ssh/config in Vim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming what you've done is created a symlink ‘~/.ssh’ to a folder named ‘ssh’ somewhere else on your system, for example ~/git/ssh, you have 2 options:

#### Solution A

inside ‘~/.vim/ftdetect/ssh.vim’ put the following line:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead */ssh/config  setf sshconfig
```

#### Solution B

Make sure that the folder which the symlink resolves to is called ‘.ssh’

The culprit file ⇒ /usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead ssh_config,*/.ssh/config  setf sshconfig
```

Comment: for neovim, `~/.config/nvim/ftdetect/ssh.vim`

Answer (score 2):

If you want ssh config syntax coloring for all files in `~/.ssh/config.d/` (or any other catalog you want) then use either solution A or B by @Shane Mulligan but put this line instead:

`au BufNewFile,BufRead ssh_config,*/.ssh/config.d/*  setf sshconfig`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to your `~/.vimrc`

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

should be enough for Vim to recognize the filetype and apply the correct syntax.

Comment: That line already exists in my .vimrc, the problem is only with the syntax of .ssh/config